# SQL/Impala: Applying another group by on the first group by output

Tags: python, sql, impala

I need to do a `group by` on top of a `group by` output. For example, in the below `table1`:

```
id   |   timestamp   |  team
----------------------------
1    |   2016-01-02  |   A
2    |   2016-02-01  |   B
1    |   2016-02-04  |   A
1    |   2016-03-05  |   A
3    |   2016-05-12  |   B
3    |   2016-05-15  |   B
4    |   2016-07-07  |   A
5    |   2016-08-01  |   C
6    |   2015-08-01  |   C
1    |   2015-04-01  |   A
```

If I do a query:

```
query = select id, max(timestamp) as latest_ts from table1' + \
           ' where timestamp > "2016-01-01 00:00:00" group by id'
```

I would have:

```
id   |   latest_ts   |
---------------------
2    |   2016-02-01  |  
1    |   2016-03-05  |   
3    |   2016-05-15  |   
4    |   2016-07-07  |   
5    |   2016-08-01  |
```

However, I am wondering if it is possible to include the `team` column like below as well?

```
id   |   latest_ts   |  team
----------------------------
2    |   2016-02-01  |   B
1    |   2016-03-05  |   A
3    |   2016-05-15  |   B
4    |   2016-07-07  |   A
5    |   2016-08-01  |   C
```

---

Ultimately, what I really need is to know how many distinct id in each team for year 2016. My expected result should be:

```
team  |  count(id)
-------------------
 A    |  2
 B    |  2
 C    |  1
```

I am trying to do another `group by` on top of the first `group by` result using the code below, but got Syntax errors.

```
import pandas as pd
query = 'select team, count(id) from ' + \
           '(select id, max(timestamp) as latest_ts from table1' + \
           ' where timestamp > "2016-01-01 00:00:00" group by id)' + \
        'group by team'  

cursor = impala_con.cursor()
cursor.execute('USE history')
cursor.execute(query)
df_result = as_pandas(cursor)
df_result
```

So I am wondering if this is something can be achieved? If so, what should be the right way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to count distinct ids why don't you use `select team, count(distinct id) from table1 where timestamp > "2016-01-01 00:00:00" group by team;`?

Comment: Great idea. Thanks!